# how to display home page after successfull login with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried `redirect()` and `$this->load->view('target_page')` but, no success for me so please help me with this:

**My controller is here:**

```
class Login_control extends CI_Controller {    
public function index() {
$this->load->model('login_model'); 
$this->load->helper('url');
if(isset($_POST['Logusername'])|| isset($_POST['Logpassword']))
{
$user = $_POST['Logusername'];
$pass = $_POST['Logpassword'];
$data = $this->login_model->login1($user,$pass);
if($data > 0 )
{
 echo '<font color="#00FF00">'. "OK".'</font>';     
$this->load->view('testing',$data);                   
 }
else 
{ echo  '<font color="#FF0000">'. "Login Failed ! Username or Password is Incorrect.".'</font>' ;                     
}  
exit();            
}  
$this->load->view('signup_view');
}
}
```

Comment: Post your model code too !!

Comment: Change || to && here `if(isset($_POST['Logusername']) && isset($_POST['Logpassword']))
`

Comment: For authentication you better use some readymade authentication library like https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Comment: Codeigniter has a form validation library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html you also can set session data in the form validation success part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You have written `echo` before redirect so, it might not work.

```
class Login_control extends CI_Controller{    
public function index()
{
$this->load->model('login_model'); 
$this->load->helper('url');
if(isset($_POST['Logusername'])|| isset($_POST['Logpassword']))
{
$user = $_POST['Logusername'];
$pass = $_POST['Logpassword'];
$data = $this->login_model->login1($user,$pass);
if($data > 0 )
{
    redirect('testing');                   
 }
else 
{ echo  '<font color="#FF0000">'. "Login Failed ! Username or Password is Incorrect.".'</font>' ;                     
}  
exit();            
}  
$this->load->view('signup_view');
}
}
```

Comment: @user2848909  Replace `testing` with your valid URL.

Comment: yes ! Its redirects successfully but I include some ajax and jquery in this code so 'testing ' page contents displaying in bottom of submit button on same page !

Comment: how to redirect it out of ajax ?

Comment: Your whole login process must be ajax based and on successful login you just replace the div with your html content return in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
class Login_control extends CI_Controller{    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('login_model'); 
        $this->load->helper('url');

        if(isset($_POST['Logusername']) && isset($_POST['Logpassword'])) # Change || to &&
        {
            $user = $_POST['Logusername'];
            $pass = $_POST['Logpassword'];

            $data = $this->login_model->login1($user,$pass);

            if($data == 1){ # check is there only one user
                echo '<font color="#00FF00">OK</font>';     
                $this->load->view('testing',$data);                   
            }
            else{ 
                echo  '<font color="#FF0000">Login Failed ! Username or Password is Incorrect.</font>' ;                     
            }             
        }  
        $this->load->view('signup_view');
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function login1($user,$pass)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= '$user' AND password = '$pass' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result); # get count of result
    return $count; # return count to controller 
}
```

Comment: Try to explain why your code code is working also what is the use of            `echo '<font color="#00FF00">OK</font>';`

Comment: @Saty i ddint get you

Comment: Just explain why your code is working for OP. what changes your have done

Comment: @user2848909 check this

Comment: Thank for your reply Abdulla

Answer (score 0):

As you are developing in codeigniter better user its inbuilt method to get and post data. For authentication u can create one library which will be autoload and check for session like userid if not found then redirect user to login page . You can create one array in that library which will defines the public / authenticated pages on bases on which you prevent user from accessing authenticated pages. You can try this for Controller :

```
class Login_control extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $Logusername = $this->input->post('Logusername', true);
        $Logpassword = $this->input->post('Logpassword', true);
        if (!empty($Logusername) && !empty($Logpassword)) {
            $user = $Logusername;
            $pass = $Logpassword;
            $data = $this->login_model->authenticate($user, $pass);
            if ($data == TRUE) {
                /* User this flashdata to display the message after redirect */
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Logged in successfully');
                redirect(site_url("dashboard"));
            } else {
                /* User this flashdata to display the message after redirect */
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Wrong Username/password');
                redirect(site_url());
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('signup_view');
    }
}
```

For Model

```
public function authenticate($Logusername, $Logpassword)
{
    $select_col = "iUserId";
    $where = "`vUserName` =?"; //*
    $where.=" AND BINARY `vPassword`=?";
    $sql = "SELECT " . $select_col . " FROM user WHERE " . $where . "";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($Logusername, $Logpassword))->result_array();
    if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
        /* Create Session and store userid */
        $this->session->set_userdata("iUserId", $result[0]["iUserId"]);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to authenticate the user. Check for hooks in Codeigniter